# returns error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Tags: typescript

gives an error I don't know what to do here is part of the code

```
const Timeout = new Map();
module.exports = async (client, message, db) => {
  let checking = db.fetch(`nitroemoji_${message.guild.id}`)
  if(checking == true)
```

Comment: forgot to add a complete error
let checking = db.fetch(`nitroemoji_${message.guild.id}`)
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Answer (score 0):

That error means it is trying to read a field called 'id' but the object containing the field is null. That implies guild is null but without a fuller example it's not possible to say why.